# How to suspend workflow and resume workflow?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have long running workflow; and I want to give user option to suspend workflow and resume it when he is ready...

How can I achieve this in wf4 ?

Answer (score 1):

WF4 uses Bookmarks now, suspend and unsuspend is only working in wf3.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Windows-Workflow-Foundation-WF4-Workflow-Services-and-Auto-Start) and [sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-6b4ffbe8) from MSDN which show how to do it.

This presumes you're using the AppFabric host. You may be able to port the idea to a non-AppFabric workflow if need be.